# What is the use of concatenate layer in CNN?

Tags: neural-networks, convolutional-neural-networks, training

I am not asking what does concatenate layer does in general in point of mathematical operation. But at feature level, what significance does it provide. Does it helps removing false negatives or does it prevents over-fitting? Do give the reference of papers regarding this topic.

Comment: Which "concatenate" layer are you talking about? Can you please link us to a CNN (implementation or definition in a paper) that uses the "concatenate" layer you're talking about?

Comment: Add layer as in Keras which is equivalent to concatenate, https://keras.io/layers/merge/